# Como gravar um DateTimePicker no banco de dados

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

Olá,

Tenho um formulário com o DateTimePicker - Short (só a data).

E no banco de dados coloquei `DataEntrada DATE`

Meu problema é, criei um método de inserção mas não sei como faço para passar o DateTimePicker por parâmetro.

Método de inserir registros:

```
public void InserirRegistros(string nome, int codigo, int minimo, int maximo, int qtd, DateTime data)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string cmdInserir = String.Format("INSERT INTO ESTOQUE(codigo,codigo,minimo,maximo,quantidade,dataEntrada) " +
                                                            "VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')", nome, codigo, minimo, maximo, qtd, data);

            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }catch(NpgsqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Evento Click do botão:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DAL acesso = new DAL();

    try
    {
        acesso.InserirRegistros(txtNomeProduto.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMinimo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMaximo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtEntrada.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dtpData.DataBindings));
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

Erro:

> ```
> System.InvalidCastException ocorrido
>   HResult=0x80004002
>   Message=Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection' no tipo 'System.IConvertible'.
>   Source=ProjetoAlpha
>   StackTrace:
>    em ProjetoAlpha.frmProduto.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\frmProduto.cs:linha 29
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>    em ProjetoAlpha.Program.Main() em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\Program.cs:linha 19
> ```

Até o momento não consegui, porque o campo na tabela é DATE (2010-01-01) e estou passando no formato errado, como arrumo isso? Será que preciso alterar o tipo do parâmetro para string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apenas troque `Convert.ToDateTime(dtpData.DataBindings)` por `dtpData.Value`

Salvo engano, se o campo for do tipo Date e você informar um datetime nos parâmetros não terá problemas.

Mas de qualquer forma, você pode utilizar outros valores:

`dtpData.Value.Date` Continua sendo um `DateTime` no C#, mas com o time zerado (01/01/2017 00:00:00)

Vamos acertar um detalhe: Não utilize concatenação de string para montar o comando SQL. Veja:

> Sua query está com 2 colunas código, e só tem 6 colunas, mas você informa 7 parâmetros no string format.

```
 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
 {
        conn.Open();

        string cmdInserir = "INSERT INTO ESTOQUE(codigo,nome,minimo,maximo,quantidade,dataEntrada) VALUES (:codigo,:nome,:minimo,:maximo,:quantidade,:dataEntrada);";

        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
        {
            NpgsqlParameter[] param = new  NpgsqlParameter[6];
            param[0] = new NpgsqlParameter("codigo", codigo);
            param[1] = new NpgsqlParameter("nome", nome);
            param[2] = new NpgsqlParameter("minimo", minimo);
            param[3] = new NpgsqlParameter("maximo", maximo);
            param[4] = new NpgsqlParameter("quantidade", quantidade);
            param[5] = new NpgsqlParameter("dataEntrada", data);
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Comment: Não da, o campo na tabela é "dataEntrada DATE" ai tem que ser no formato "2010-05-01"

Comment: Mas ai no caso eu tenho que alterar o parametro que está DateTime data, para string

Comment: alterado @WSS, sobre colocar como string, você poderia fazer aquela formatação dentro do método, mas acho melhor fazer como coloquei agora

Comment: Vou testar esta forma, porque esta dando problema de NullException, eu tinha visto este erro no insert e tinha arrumado já

Comment: obs: se a coluna código for do tipo `SERIAL` você não precisa informar ela no insert, porque o postgresql irá gerar a sequencia automaticamente. Sobre o erro `NullException`, informe qual linha está ocorrendo

Comment: Ronann https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245784/nullreferenceexception-ao-tentar-gravar-no-banco-de-dados

Answer (score 0):

A forma de se obter a data selecionada no `DateTimePicker` é a seguinte:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var dataSelecionada = dateTimePicker1.Value;
}
```

Isto te retornará um objeto do tipo `DateTime`então você pode passar para o seu método.

[Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Não funciona, ele pega a data completa exemplo: 13/10/2017  07:39:04

Comment: qual error ele está retornando ?!

Comment: Este erro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245784/nullreferenceexception-ao-tentar-gravar-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: Mas esse erro não tem nada haver com a data, não entendi o downvote, sendo que o erro é de referência nula e não tem nada haver com a pergunta.

Comment: a principio eu achava que era por conta do formato, ai fui alterando e cheguei nesta conclusão também

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto.

No começo da query adicione : "**[set dateformat dmy](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**", no meu caso, eu uso SQL SERVER.

```
string query = "set dateformat dmy INSERT...";
```

Para pegar o valor do datetimepicker, tente :

```
dateTimePicker.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

apenas troque Convert.ToDateTime(dtpData.DataBindings) por dtpData.Value.Date

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DAL acesso = new DAL();

    try
    {
        acesso.InserirRegistros(txtNomeProduto.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMinimo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMaximo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtEntrada.Text), dtpData.Value.Data);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado com sucesso!");
    }
}
```