# NullReferenceException ao tentar gravar no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Estou com esse erro, quando vou gravar os dados do form no banco.

> Erro: System.NullReferenceException:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException ocorrido
>   HResult=0x80004003
>   Message=Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   Source=ProjetoAlpha
>   StackTrace:
>    em ProjetoAlpha.frmProduto.btnGravar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\frmProduto.cs:linha 29
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>    em ProjetoAlpha.Program.Main() em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\Program.cs:linha 19
> ```

Este é o método para inserir:

Está é minha tabela no PostGresql:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está é a classe completa da conexão e dos métodos:

```
using System;
using Npgsql;
using System.Data;

namespace ProjetoAlpha
{
    class DAL
    {
        static string serverName = "localhost";
        static string port = "5432";
        static string userName = "postgres";
        static string password = "adm";
        static string databaseName = "dbestoque";
        NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
        string ConnString = null;

        public DAL()
        {
            ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id{2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                       serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);    
        }

        public DataTable GetTodosRegistros()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string cmdSeleciona = "SELECT * FROM estoque order by id_produto";

                    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdSeleciona, conn))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }    
            return dt;
        }

        public DataTable GetRegistroPorId(int id)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string cmdSeleciona = "SELECT * FROM ESTOQUE WHERE codigo =" + id;

                    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdSeleciona, conn))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public void InserirRegistros(string nome, int codigo, int minimo, int maximo, int qtd, DateTime data)
        {
            try
            {
                using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    string cmdInserir = String.Format("INSERT INTO ESTOQUE(nome,codigo,minimo,maximo,quantidade,dataEntrada) " +
                                                                    "VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", nome, codigo, minimo, maximo, qtd, data);

                    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }catch(NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Botão Gravar:

```
 private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DAL acesso = new DAL();

            try
            {
                acesso.InserirRegistros(txtNomeProduto.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMinimo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMaximo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtEntrada.Text), dtpData.Value);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado com sucesso!");
            }
        }
```

Retirei os try,catch e finally e deu erro na classe de Inserir dados:

```
System.ArgumentException ocorrido
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Keyword not supported: user idpostgres;password
Parameter name: keyword
  Source=Npgsql
  StackTrace:
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   em System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   em ProjetoAlpha.DAL.InserirRegistros(String nome, Int32 codigo, Int32 minimo, Int32 maximo, Int32 qtd, DateTime data) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\DAL.cs:linha 91
   em ProjetoAlpha.frmProduto.btnGravar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\frmProduto.cs:linha 26
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   em ProjetoAlpha.Program.Main() em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\Program.cs:linha 19
```

Comment: tira esse monte de try catch aí... e outra...se der erro e cair do catch, no final ainda assim você exibe "Cadastrado com sucesso" ?

Comment: Na verdade está caindo só catch e não mostra nada além do erro, pra ser sincero eu estou seguindo um tutorial na net que o cara fazia isso também http://www.macoratti.net/13/07/c_pgsql2.htm

Comment: já aprendi muito com os tutoriais dele, mas nesse aí... nun ficou legal não... rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o erro de nullException está acontecendo no `conn.Close();` porque a `conn` é nula. Aconteceu um erro ao tentar criá-la.

Acredito que esteja apenas faltando um `=` na sintaxe na string de conexão:

> Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};

Comment: Fiz essa mudança mas continua dando o erro e caindo no `catch`

Comment: tire os try catch de dentro do método inserir, e deixa aparecer a stacktrace pra ver onde o erro acontece. Ou coloque breakpoint nos catch pra testar

Comment: Rovann olha a edição que fiz sem os `try / catch / finally`

Comment: o erro está na string de conexão... tá faltando um = no User ID

Comment: .. era isso mesmo, tava tão preocupado com outras coisas que nem parei pra notar isso.. obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: por nada, só uma sugestão, que inclusive aprendi aqui na comunidade, de evitar esse monte de try catch... tem algumas questões bacanas sobre isso aqui =]